# Regex for positive lookahead thousand separator that would not mach numbers after dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using following regex to 'insert' commas into numbers in javascript.

```
(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

It works very well with integers however when working with decimal numbers it fails cases like 10000.001223456 (result is 1,234,568.0,000,454,554)

What happens regex looks ahead after '.' finds match and replaces it with ,

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/tD2jO6/2)

I tried remedy it [by adding negative lookbehind](https://regex101.com/r/tD2jO6/1) without luck,

```
((\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))(?<!\.))
```

since '.' can be at any position in sequence and I cannot use `*` nor `+`.

**How do I make regex that would not match after some specific symbol (in this specific case after '.')?**

Comment: Instead of using look-behind/forward you should just explicitly say what you allow. You can use `+` and `*` with groups, for example: `\d{1-3}(?:,\d{3})+?(?:\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this only in 3 steps:

1. Split the number into integer and decimal parts
2. Modify the integer part
3. Join.

There is no variable-width look-behind in JS that would be very handy here.

```js
var s = ".12345680000454554";
//Beforehand, perhaps, it is a good idea to check if the number has a decimal part
if (s.indexOf(".") > -1) { 
    var splts = s.split(".");
    //alert(splts);
    splts[0] = splts[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
    //alert(splts[0]);
    s = splts.join(".");
    alert(s);
  }
else
  {
     alert(s.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,'));
  }
```