# Regex - getting position with Regex but without using \B

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex places commas after groups of three digits starting from the right.

```
"123456".replace(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/.',')
```

gives 123,456, which is correct.

But the regex has no \B. So, not sure how it works now.

Comment: Why it should require `\B` when lookahead is there to make sure multiple of 3 digit set is ahead of current position.

Comment: And how do you suppose to handle `12345.56789`? Please see [my answer to some similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074921/regex-for-positive-lookahead-thousand-separator-that-would-not-mach-numbers-afte/32075133#32075133).

Comment: @airnet: Please check if my previous answer solves your problem. If not, please provide sample input with expected output, together with your attempts and explanation *why* they do not work.